# Unable to reset multiple checkbox values after submitting in formik

Tags: reactjs, formik-material-ui

So I am using Formik and MUI. I am unable to reset checkbox values after submitting.

I have tried **useRef**, **states**, **setFieldsValue** to manipulate this. But no luck. (I might be doing something in the wrong way probably)

Let me know if there is any mistake or workaround that I am missing. Or if you have any suggestions for this.

Below is the code that can be refferred.

**Main Form**

```
const LeadForm = () => {
    const [loc, setLoc] = useState({});

    const handleSubmitForm =(values, formik) =>{
        let googleLocation = [];
        Object.keys(loc).forEach((e) => {
            loc[e]===true && googleLocation.push(e);
        })

        const postData={
            user_google_location: googleLocation.join(','),
        }
       
        Axios.post(`...url`, qs.stringify(postData))
        .then(response =>{
          ...some toast
        }).catch(err=>console.log(err))
    }
    let location = [
       {
         id: 1,
         typeValue: Delhi
       },
       {
         id: 2,
         typeValue: Punjab
       }
    ]

    return (
        <div className={Styles.FormDiv}>
            <Formik
                initialValues={{
                    user_google_location:''
                }}
                onSubmit={ (values) => {
                    handleSubmitForm(values);
                }}
            >
            {({
                values,
                errors,
                handleChange,                
                handleSubmit,
                }) => {
                return <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    {
                        location.map((e, index) => 
                        <div key={index}>
                            <CheckBoxSelectors
                                id={e.id}
                                values={values}
                                setLoc={setLoc}
                                loc={loc}
                                label={e.typeValue}
                            />
                        </div> 
                        )
                    }
                    <button type="button" className={Styles.SubmitButton} 
                        onClick={() => {
                            handleSubmitForm(values);
                            handleReset();
                        }}
                    >
                        SUBMIT
                    </button>
                </Form>}
            }
            </Formik>
        </div>
    )
};

export default LeadForm;
```

**CheckBoxSelectors Component**

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import FormGroup from '@material-ui/core/FormGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';

const BlueCheckbox = withStyles({
    root: {
      '&$checked': {
        color: "#1c75c0",
      },
    },
    checked: {},
  })((props) => <Checkbox color="default" {...props} />);


export default function CheckboxLabels(props) {
  const {label, values, id, loc, setLoc} = props
  const handleChange = (event, value) => {
    let obj = {};
    obj[event.target.name] = event.target.checked;
    setLoc({...loc, ...obj});
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormGroup>
         {...normal div...}
         <FormControlLabel
            control={
              <BlueCheckbox
                checked={values[checkBox[0].name]}
                onChange={handleChange}
                name={checkBox[0].name}
                color="primary"
              />
            }
         />
      </FormGroup>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: https://formik.org/docs/migrating-v2#resetform
this can help u.

Comment: @Quyen Nguyen Checked the documentation. But my code is a little customized. Also, I am manipulating values with the states and not the setFieldValue (as it was not working). So the documentation isn't helping.

Answer (score 0):

https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#resetform-nextstate-partialformikstatevalues--void
I think that it can help your case.

e/g:

```
<Formik
   initialValues={{
      ...
   }}
   onSubmit={ (values, actions) => {
      handleSubmitForm(values);
      actions.resetForm({
         values: {
           // the type of `values` inferred to be Blog
           title: '',
           image: '',
           body: '',
         },
      });
   }}
>
```

or

```
const handleSubmitForm = (values, actions) => {
    your logic...
    actions.resetForm({values: {...}})
}
<Formik
       initialValues={{
          ...
       }}
       onSubmit={ (values, actions) => {
          handleSubmitForm(values, actions);
       }}
    >
```

Comment: So, my onSubmit prop is hardly working. Hence, I kept the functionality on the onClick of the submit button.  Where I have used handleReset functionality. It seems to be more of a UI issue. Because the value is resetting to its initialValue. However, the checked mark still shows in the UI. I guess there should be something to be edited in the second component, i.e., CheckBoxSelectors. I tried every possible way, but still hard luck.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by my own!

**CheckBoxSelectors Component**

```
    const BlueCheckbox = withStyles({
        root: {
          '&$checked': {
            color: "#1c75c0",
          },

          //changed mui class on each event

          '&:not($checked) .MuiIconButton-label:after':{
            color: 'white'
          }
        },
        checked: {},
      })((props) => <Checkbox color="default" {...props} />);
    
    
    export default function CheckboxLabels(props) {

      //previous code
    
        <BlueCheckbox
          checked={loc[checkBox[0].name]}  --> changed loc[...] from values[...]
          onChange={handleChange}
          name={checkBox[0].name}
                                    ----> removed color="primary"
        />
    
    
      //previous code
    }
```

For the time being this is working. Still open to any suggestions if any.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `onChange` from `checkbox` and add in `FormControlLabel`. I did in my project like this:

```
<FormControlLabel
   control={<Checkbox checked={formik.values.percentage} />}
   label="Percentage"
   name="percentage"
   onChange={formik.handleChange}
/>
```